# How to test whether \ is in a string?

Tags: r, regex, string, boolean

I am working with the following string:

```
Potent_Abb <- "GR\xdcNE"
```

I want to test whether the string contains the "\" in it. So it produces a boolean (True or False) as the output.

Any help you could offer would be appreciated.

Comment: That string actually doesn't contain a slash. The `\xdc` is an ASCII escape sequence inside your string. You have some non-ASCII character in there from some where. It looks like the string might be using the Latin-1 encoding and is actually the value "GRÜNE"

Comment: Is there a way to test (boolean) for this?

Comment: You can't grep on a value that isn't there. Again, there is no slash in that string at all. If you do `cat(Potent_Abb)` you'll probably see the "real" value.

Comment: How can I test for a � value then? (What i get when i use ```cat(Potent_Abb)```

Comment: Assuming you are on Windows, you can do `grepl("\xdc","GR\xdcNE")`. Again the `\xdc` is all one character, not 4 separate characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from [Handling Strings with R](https://www.gastonsanchez.com/r4strings/character-sets.html#metacharacters-inside-character-sets)

> Not all metacharacters become literal characters when they appear inside a character set. The exceptions are the closing bracket ], the dash -, the caret ^, and the backslash \.

An answer to your question "How can I test a backslash`(\)` is in a string?" can be found [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html):

> ...If `\` is used as an escape character in regular expressions, how do you match a literal `\`? Well you need to escape it, creating the regular expression `\\`. To create that regular expression, you need to use a string, which also needs to escape `\`. That means to match a literal `\` you need to write `\\\\` — you need four backslashes to match one!

An example using your string using `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)

Potent_Abb <- "GR\xdcNE"
writeLines(Potent_Abb, con = stdout()) # cat(Potent_Abb)
#GR�NE
# to detect if the string has a backslash
str_detect(Potent_Abb, "\\\\")
# FALSE

#Let's add a backslash literal at the end 
# we need to escape the '\` using a '\` to represent it as a literal, hence `\\`
Potent_Abb <- "GR\xdcNE\\"
writeLines(Potent_Abb, con = stdout()) # cat(Potent_Abb)
#GR�NE\

str_detect(Potent_Abb, "\\\\")
# TRUE
```

Hope that adds something somewhere if not a future reference to myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iconv` to replace ASCII characters with some other character, and then match that character instead:

```r
Potent_Abb <- "GR\xdcNE"

grepl("#", iconv(Potent_Abb, "ASCII", sub = "#"))

# [1] TRUE
```